Error "Failed to retrieve server info BSONError: Invalid UTF-8 string in BSON" document when connecting to MongoDB
I downloaded the MongoDB app (community version) and tried to create a new connection. I have not opened any database, this is my first opening of the application.The following window appeared with the message "Failed to retrieve server info BSONError: Invalid UTF-8 string in BSON".  How can this be solved?
I tried setting enableUtf8Validation=false, downloading and reinstalling the app and downloading previous version of the app.

The MongoDB app you had downloaded and tried is MongoDB Compass, a tool to interact with MongoDB database. Make sure you have a MongoDB database server installed and started. Then, connect to it from Compass.

I have just completed this process on a Windows.
Download and install MongoDB 7.0 Community Edition from https://fastdl.mongodb.org/windows/mongodb-windows-x86_64-7.0.11-signed.msi
Choose a full installation as it includes MongoDB Compass. Note: the installation became non-responsive when it reached the Compass section of the installation, so I cancelled the installation. The result of this was that it actually installed Compass and not MongoDB itself. I simply ran the install again, de-selecting Compass this time.
See more notes here: https://www.stylus.co.za/installing-mongodb-on-windows/
